# Kendo grid sorting doesnt work after grouping

Tags: sorting, kendo-grid, grouping

I have a Kendo UI grid. I want to display data as grouped and sorted, but seems that doesnt work. In my dataSource i have

```
                   serverPaging: true,
                   serverSorting: true,
                   serverFiltering: true, 
                   group: {
                        field: "ApplicationName",
                        dir: "desc"
                   },
                   sort: {
                        field: "VersionTo",
                        dir: "desc"
                   },
```

Grouping works...But data is not sorted. 
If i remove group property then i get data sorted but not grouped. 
From a google search i see that serverGrouping is not enabled, so grouping happen on client-side and change sorting. But if i add in my configuration "serverGrouping: true," i get this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined".

How can integrate grouping and sorting?